# Python: How i Can print only a particular string starting with a specific character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, startswith, ends-with

I have a text file which contains list of urls which looks like as follows:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Egyptian-Comfort-1800-Count-4-Piece-Bed-Sheet-Set-Deep-Pocket-Bed-Sheets/142436469971?epid=1760442729&hash=item2129e00cd3%3Ag%3A7gIAAOSw3YBdRVJd&_trkparms=%2526rpp_cid%253D601435485fceeb223c6f4511&var=442541824291

Here  i only want to print epid=1760442729 while reading the text file.

I have tried:

```
result = []`
with open('deals.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('?epid='):
        break
    result.append(line)
print(result[0].split('epid='))
```

But i am not getting as expected result.

Any help or suggestions will be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your text file look like? I'm assuming you have a url per line, which will never work with your code as no url will start with `?epid=`. Maybe read character by character, look for `?epid=`, read everything until the `&`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.I made changes and it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

s = """https://www.ebay.com/itm/Egyptian-Comfort-1800-Count-4-Piece-Bed-Sheet-Set-Deep-Pocket-Bed-Sheets/142436469971?epid=1760442729&hash=item2129e00cd3%3Ag%3A7gIAAOSw3YBdRVJd&_trkparms=%2526rpp_cid%253D601435485fceeb223c6f4511&var=442541824291
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Egyptian-Comfort-1800-Count-4-Piece-Bed-Sheet-Set-Deep-Pocket-Bed-Sheets/142436469971?epid=172442729&hash=item2129e00cd3%3Ag%3A7gIAAOSw3YBdRVJd&_trkparms=%2526rpp_cid%253D601435485fceeb223c6f4511&var=442541824291"""

for i in re.findall(r'epid=(\d+)&', s, re.MULTILINE):
    print(f'epid = {i}')
```

```
epid = 1760442729
epid = 172442729
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) @Epsi95

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a substring if the same structure is always used

```
result = []
with open('deals.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    a= line.find('epid=')
    b= line.find('&hash=')
    print(line[a:b])
    result.append(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) @MarcosT

Answer (score 0):

Use the library that was designed to parse URL.

Example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

URL='https://www.ebay.com/itm/Egyptian-Comfort-1800-Count-4-Piece-Bed-Sheet-Set-Deep-Pocket-Bed-Sheets/142436469971?epid=1760442729&hash=item2129e00cd3%3Ag%3A7gIAAOSw3YBdRVJd&_trkparms=%2526rpp_cid%253D601435485fceeb223c6f4511&var=442541824291'

url_component = urlparse(URL)
query_component = parse_qs(url_component.query)
epid_data = query_component['epid'][0]
print(f'epid = {epid_data}')
```